# How to compare two page's UV/PV data and whole traffic in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Say I install GA successfully on my website site.com

I have two url:

site.com/page-a
site.com/page-b

I can see detailed information of each in "Content"->"All Pages". But I don't know how to compare them? I remember the old version of GA can do this but now I just don't know how to do.

I also want to know how to compare the data with the whole site's data.

Thanks very much for any kind of tips!

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible if you create two segments for each page and apply that segment using page filter this way you can compare data between two pages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you please tell me more details on how to create two segments?

Comment: Create segments with 1) page contains /page-a and 2) page contains /page-b